# Does "return await" makes any difference?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Is there any difference between

```
const foo = async () => {
  // some other code that uses await
  return await bar()
}
```

and

```
const foo = async () => {
  // some other code that uses await
  return bar()
}
```

Where `bar` is a function that returns a promise.

Is the `await` redundant or does it make any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is redundant.

It extracts the value from the promise returned by bar, and then resolves the promise returned by `foo` with it.

If you return `bar`'s promise directly, then the promise returned by `foo` adopts it to the same effect.

Comment: It is redundant in the sense that the result will be same if you call `foo().then(..)` or `await foo()`. However, I want to ask if the first approach is going to take more time at the `foo` function since you need to wait for the result of `bar()` before wrapping it in the returning Promise, whereas second approach just return the Promise of bar() directly without trying to resolve it (at least that's what it seems to me; I am uncertain)

Comment: The first approach does not **wait** for the result of `bar()`. It's really the same thing in practical terms. JavaScript doesn't "wait".

Comment: Does the first approach cause memory leak or some performance issue?

Answer (score 2):

If the Promise is **rejected**, **the error** would be thrown in different places, in the two example you wrote.

**In the first,** a rejected error would happen inside `foo`.

**In the second,** a rejected error would happen to the function that called `foo`

Comment: In my example, I don't think it would make any difference between throwing an error inside  `foo` or by the function that called `foo`, it would only add one more function to a stacktrace, BUT if I had an try catch around that `return`, then it would make a difference right? Because it would be handled by `foo`'s try catch and not another from the function that called `foo`

Comment: Yes I believe so. And abt the stacktrace, it's important in some (big) projects (:

Answer (score -3):

Yes.

If the function bar() returns a Promise, in the second case foo will return a pending Promise (a Promise that has not yet resolved). In the first case, foo will return the data the Promise resolved with after waiting for the Promise to resolve